# Invalid drawable tag vector - appcompat-v7:24.1.1

Tags: java, android

OK I've read most of available answer on similar questions but nothing fixed my problem

gradle `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'`

```
android {
   defaultConfig {
      minSdkVersion 16
      targetSdkVersion 24
      vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
   }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
}
```

activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ViewItem"
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix">

    ...

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical|center|center_horizontal"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_car" />

    ...

</ScrollView>
```

vector ic_car.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:viewportWidth="24">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#5c5c5c"
        android:pathData="M18.92 6.01C18.72 5.42 18.16 5 17.5 5h-11c-.66 0-1.21 .42 -1.42 1.01L3 12v8c0
.55 .45 1 1 1h1c.55 0 1-.45 1-1v-1h12v1c0 .55 .45 1 1 1h1c.55 0 1-.45
1-1v-8l-2.08-5.99zM6.5 16c-.83 0-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5S5.67 13 6.5 13s1.5 .67 1.5
1.5S7.33 16 6.5 16zm11 0c-.83 0-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5s.67-1.5 1.5-1.5 1.5 .67 1.5
1.5-.67 1.5-1.5 1.5zM5 11l1.5-4.5h11L19 11H5z" />
    <path android:pathData="M0 0h24v24H0z" />
</vector>
```

my activity class extends `AppCompatActivity` and all `android:src` tags are changed to `app:srcCompat` but still I see `Invalid drawable tag vector` error on the `minSdkVersion` which is set to `16`.

Comment: did you try using `android:src` instead of `app:srcCompat`.

Comment: @MuddassirAhmed yes of course I did

Comment: Does it happen only in release version, or in all versions?

Comment: @lionscribe as Zeke says, in all versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem got solved itself after updating to Android studio 2.2

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the crash happened due to using [Resources.getDrawable(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawable(int)) to get the vector drawable on pre-lollipop devices. I was trying to create a drawable to pass into
[ImageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)).

[Google Blog Post for Android Support Library 23.2:](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html)

> As of Android Support Library 23.3.0, support vector drawables can
>   only be loaded via app:srcCompat or setImageResource().

Solution: Use [VectorDrawableCompat.create(Resources, int, Theme)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawableCompat.html#create(android.content.res.Resources,%20int,%20android.content.res.Resources.Theme)) to create the drawable.

You can also use [ImageView.setImageResource(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int)) however this will read/decode the bitmap on the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

Truth is, looking at your code, it should work in any version of the library, as you are using only the srcCompat attribute.
 
One issue I suspect, is that your vector is in a drawable-21 folder, while in the regular Drawable folder you have single file that references these Drawables. This was a method done in early versions of the library, but does not work anymore due to changes below. Just move the actual vector file to the Drawable folder.
 
We have had sometimes similar issues that were solved by changing the `ImageView` to an `AppCompatImageView`. Even though the library is supposed to do this automatically, it seems that sometimes it doesn't. 
It is still possible that the code is breaking if your vector is part of a compound image, for example a layered image. Or it's breaking somewhere else for which you have not posted the code, for example if you are setting a vector as the leftImage on an ImageButton. These functionalities have been removed in 23.3, as @Zeke has answered. Nonetheless, it was returned in 23.4, made usable by adding the following to your activity

```
static {
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
}
```

They still warn you it can cause memory leaks. See https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88#.s48hqaw1u, though for minimal use it shouldn't be an issue.

A simple workaround would be to create the Drawable and set it in code. Something like this;

```
Drawable icon = AppCompatDrawableManager.get().getDrawable(context, resVectorID);  
// Set it for example as a left image of button
button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( icon, null, null, null );
```

I have not tested this, and have no ideas if this causes memory issues or not. Would love it if someone can follow up.

Comment: Need to do 3 things;
1) `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` on `gradle`;
2) `static { AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true); }` on Activity rendering SVG;
3) `app:srcCompat` instead of `android:src` in `ImageView`; Even missing one of them _will_ **crash** your app - as of `24.2.0`

Answer (score 0):

I did like this:

```
public static final Drawable getMyDrawable(Context context, int id) {
     final int version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
     if (version >= 21) {
         return ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, id);
     } else {
         return VectorDrawableCompat.create(context.getResources(), id,  context.getTheme());
     }
}
```